# How to match these two styles / how to get this grainy texture?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, texture, filter

We got some Graphics done by a professional. Now I'd like to modify them and add some objects. He used a "special effect" maybe a filter, or is just done with a brush? What would be the easiest way to achieve that effect?

[image: left the grainy graphics, drawn by the professional, on the right my drawing]

Comment: Not totally related to the question but make sure your designer is OK with you modifying his work, otherwise you might get into legal trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your advice :) Our client got these graphics from his designer, now we are making him a website which the designer has also partly already seen. So he is aware of us modifying his artwork. It would cost our client too much to let him design alls of the graphics.

Comment: Can't you check which textures have been applied yourself?   Use the layers and appearance tab to find out what has been done.

Comment: I can't. These are no Effects or Lyers in the EPS files. Every scratch is an vector..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to identify the styles you want to match or reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a similar effect with some grain effects...

Say we're starting with this:

[image]

Use the Mesh Tool (<kbd>U</kbd>) to add some shading (just add some mesh points and adjust the colors with only the points you want to adjust selected):

[image]

[image]

Add some grain. There are a couple of effects that will give you a similar look; I used a "Film Grain" here (*Effect → Artistic → Film Grain...*). I used the effect on a duplicate layer then reduced the opacity to reduce the intensity of the effect...

[image]

[image]

You can combine a number of grain effects for more grain.

A useful tip... use the Appearance panel, where you can add a number of fills and strokes and effects to those specific fills etc. all on a single object...

[image]

Overlay a [paper texture](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=paper+texture&tbm=isch) for the overall texture (just place a texture above your artwork and adjust the opacity and blending mode to your liking)...

[image]

Comment: Woooow, its the whole tutorial! Thanks a lot! :) Have nice Easter holidays!

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say it's a whole tutorial but it's a good start. Happy holidays to you too.

Comment: I already have some Illustrator experience, so this is just perfect for me :)